# Using combineLatest unbinds this from angular service method?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

[This test service (Stackblitz) )](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-this-inside-combine-latest) uses `combineLatest` inside the constructor to call a service method:

```
  constructor() {
    console.log("TEST SERVICE CONSTRUCTED")

    this.setParameters.bind(this)
    this.assignFixedParameters.bind(this)

    combineLatest(
      of(true),
      of(false),
      this.setParameters).pipe(
        untilDestroyed(this)).subscribe()
  }

  setParameters(
    fixedParameters: boolean) {
    console.log("THIS IS: ", this)

    this.assignFixedParameters()
  }
  public op:any
  private assignFixedParameters() {
    console.log("CALLING ASSIGN FIXED PARAMETERS")
    this.op = this.fop
  }
  public fop = {
    sku: 'sku123'
  }
```

IIUC because of the call`this.setParameters.bind(this)` this should be the value of the angular service instance when `setParameters` is called by `combineLatest` however it is equal to `CombineLatestSubscriber` instead, therefore `this.assignFixedParameters()` does not get called.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bind()` doesn't call a function. It **returns another function** with a specific `this` context. If you don't store it or execute it, the returned function is lost and garbage collected.

I guess what you want to do is:

```
this.setParameters = this.setParameters.bind(this)
this.assignFixedParameters = this.assignFixedParameters.bind(this)
```

You could also replace them with [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) that "capture" `this` when they are declared, I guess it would be cleaner since these functions don't need to be attached to the service class.